# lower bound for sum of distinct n-th roots of unity

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, roots-of-unity

Given a positive integer $n$, define $\zeta = e^{2\pi i/n}$ and define $s: \mathbb Z^n \to \mathbb C$$$s(\vec x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x_k \zeta^k$$

Let us consider the set $S = \{ |s(\vec x)| : \vec x \in \{0,1\}^n\} \setminus \{0\}$. Is it possible  to find an explicit $\vec x \in \{0,1\}^n \setminus \{ \vec 0\}$ such that $|s(\vec x)|$ is minimal, that is $|s(\vec x)| = \min S$?

Or alternatively is there an known lower bound for $\min S$?

My thought was to find a more general result for $T  = \{ |s(\vec x)| : \vec x \in \mathbb Z^n\} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ instead of $S$, but a lower bound of this set there would probably be worse than one for $S$.

Comment: Take a look at this question from Terry Tao: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46068/how-small-can-a-sum-of-a-few-roots-of-unity-be in mathoverflow, in particular to Gerry Myerson's answer, it might help.

Comment: @EstebanCrespi Thank you very much! It seems that it is a rather hard problem if even Terry Tao has to ask for an answer.